# Extract data from Foxit Reader textbox comments using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

Consider that you have a pdf document with this **no-OCR** text:

"I am Sam, I am 28 years old and tomorrow is april/18/2018."

Is it possible to insert form controls right below "Sam", "28" and "april/18/2018", so that the user can type into the form controls exactly those informations, and them those informations from the form controls can be read by the programming code?

Could iTextSharp do that? Or maybe a simpler tool?

**EDIT 1: Below I will try to make my goal more clear (sorry my english).**

In my job I have to extract a lot of information from old scanned documents with no-OCR. Apply OCR on them is not a option. What I would like to do is: (a) I open the pdf document and start reading it. (b) Everytime I found a information that I will have to use, like a data birth, I would like to insert/apply/put/create/set a text box near it (below for example), and then type that date birth inside the text box. (c) After finishing the task of insert all textboxes I want (names, ages, date births, incomes, etc), and type in them the information read from the pdf, I would like to be able to treat all that information inside the textboxes inside my programming code, in C# for example.

[image: Text-boxes inserted and typed-in by the user. Here I used the text-box feature of Foxit Reader, that is like what I want.]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you illustrate it a bit more?

Comment: Hello, mkl, I edited the text to make it more clear, and added a screenshot.

Comment: *"I open the pdf document and start reading it."* - Which program do you want to open the PDF with? Which kind of annotations you can create, depends on what that program offers.

Comment: Can I use a programming language to read the textboxes of a pdf which have textboxed comments inserted using the Foxit Reader textbox feature? That would be suffice.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF. I'm pretty sure the answer is *yes, iText can extract those textboxed comments* but I'd like to check before. Theoretically Foxit Reader could garble everything up too badly... I don't believe it does but I have seen weirder things.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ak8iomosow8ocd4/HelloFOXIT.pdf

Comment: Yes, you can extract the comments of those annotations, they correctly are contained in the **Contents** entries of the annotation dictionaries.

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:itext]. This tag predominantly is for questions concerning the old iText versions up to 5.5.x. The current iText versions are 7.1.x, though, which usually is indicated using the [tag:itext7] tag. So, are you indeed looking for an iText 5 solution or actually for an iText 7 one?

Comment: Thank you mkl! Glad to know it is feaseble using iText. I edited the tags to reach all forms of iText since from what I can see all of them can do it (extract information from Foxit Reader textbox comments). Do you suggest a better title for the question, so that it can reach more interested people?

Comment: Well, the title is ok. Merely the fact that this question now has an accepted answer might make it disappear for numerous people as they only consider questions for answering which they perceive as "unresolved" (i.e. not having an accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I unchecked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iText 7 you can extract the textbox comments like this:

```java
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("HelloFOXIT.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader)   ) {
    for (int pageNr = 1; pageNr <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); pageNr++) {
        System.out.printf("\n\nPage %d\n\n", pageNr);
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNr);
        for (PdfAnnotation pdfAnnotation : page.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.printf("- %s\n", pdfAnnotation.getContents());
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Page 1

- 28
- 18/04/2018
- SAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iText, it is possible to extract the comments inserted in a Foxit Reader pdf *Callout* feature. As answered by mkl in the comments of the question, those Foxit Reader comments are *"contained in the Contents entries of the annotation dictionaries."*